# C# LINQ Orderby on parent only in hierarchical parent-child relationship data

Tags: c#, linq

I have an interesting problem in LINQ and I am not sure how to solve it. Here is what my data looks like

I have a list of Send objects(`List<Send>`) where Send object has the following properties

```
public class Send
{   
    public string messageName { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }        
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

where Port can be `PortA, PortB`, etc. Type can only be `"receive"` or `"transmit"` and messageName can be

```
0_firstmessage
1_secondmessage
2_thirdmessage
```

> messageName always have an identifier at the start 0,1,2....N.

My current list has data like the following. A few things to note in data

1. My data is already sorted according to Ports. So, PortA data comes
   first followed by PortB.
2. Each message of type "receive" is followed by 0 or N transmit messages group.
3. Each transmit message always has a parent receive.

My data:

```
MESSAGENAME, PORT  , TYPE  
    - 0_message , PortA , receive
       - 1_message , PortA , transmit
       - 3_message , PortA , transmit
       - 7_message , PortA , transmit
    - 8_message , PortA , receive
       - 9_message , PortA , transmit

    - 2_message , PortB , receive
    - 4_message , PortB , receive
       - 5_message , PortB , transmit
       - 6_message , PortB , transmit
    - 10_message, PortB , receive
       - 11_message , PortB , transmit
```

My final output should be like this.

```
 MESSAGENAME, PORT  , TYPE  
- 0_message , PortA , receive
   - 1_message , PortA , transmit
   - 3_message , PortA , transmit
   - 7_message , PortA , transmit
- 2_message , PortB , receive
- 4_message , PortB , receive
   - 5_message , PortB , transmit
   - 6_message , PortB , transmit
- 8_message , PortA , receive
   - 9_message , PortA , transmit
- 10_message, PortB , receive
   - 11_message , PortB , transmit
```

I want to ORDERBY based on MESSAGE_NAME for "receive" type messages only. The child "transmit" messages should stay intact.

I searched alot online but I am not sure how to write this LINQ query.

Here is a example: You can play around here.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/DKOOk2

Comment: Add a property to your class `public Send Parent { get; set; }` (and possibly the inverse children collection). Set the parents of all the children. Then you should be able to simply sort by `messageName` where there are no parents. For each parent, then print the children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a solution with an assumption that you receive `receive` first followed by `transmit` type messages.

```
int gid=0;
var results = messages.Select(m => new 
                     {                                 // Rank each message 
                        m.Type.Equals("Receive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) ? ++gid: gid, 
                        message=m 
                     })
    .GroupBy(g=>g.groupid) // Group them on Rank
    .OrderBy(g=>int.Parse(g.First().message.messageName.Split('_')[0]))  // apply Sort
    .SelectMany(c=>c.Select(x=>x.message)) // flatten structure .
    .ToList() ;
```

Check working [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wldOrA)

Comment: It does not work properly. I have updated your example with the complete data that I mentioned in question description. https://dotnetfiddle.net/DKOOk2 . As you can see in the output, 8_message should come first than 10_message

Comment: Ahh.. I got it, let me fix it.

Comment: Fixed it, check now.

Comment: Thank you for reworking your example. But your query outputs the data in original format. I want the data in final output (as mentioned in question). I have updated the fiddler because you have "Receive" instead of "receive" in your data.https://dotnetfiddle.net/oNKUhC

Comment: Solution is correct, in your example there was a typo. It should be "Receive" not "receive".

Comment: Let me make it case insenstive.

Comment: Check now, it should be fine.

Comment: seems to be working fine. Can you please add a little bit of description on how this query is working ?

Comment: I checked against my real application and it works fine there. It would be great if you can add some details on how the query actually works. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below.

```
    public class Send : IComparable<Send>
    {
        public string messageName { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }


        public int CompareTo(Send other)
        {
            int results = 0;
            if (this.messageName != other.messageName)
            {
                results = this.messageName.CompareTo(other.messageName);
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.Port != other.Port)
                {
                    results = this.Port.CompareTo(other.Port);
                }
                else
                {
                    results = this.Type.CompareTo(other.Type);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looking at my answer the code will not work.  I think you need to have the transmit messages be a child of the receive messages so when you sort the transmit messages stay with the same receive message.

Comment: I donot understand this. How is this related to my question. Can you please add some description.

Comment: Custom comparison required using IComparable.  The OrderBy will use the CompareTo() method of the class.  So you can just use OrderBy and the CompareTo() method will do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this LINQ can help you:

```
var a = mylist.OrderBy(x => x.MESSAGENAME).Where(y => y.TYPE == "receive")
                      .Concat(mylist.Where(z => z.TYPE!= "receive"));
```

As a result you will get IEnumerable where first go ordered Sends by message type receive and second - all the rest Sends unordered.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work. Here is the fiddler. https://dotnetfiddle.net/VHDkMb

Comment: In your case you need to put receive with capital letter: Where(y => y.Type == "Receive")

Answer (score 0):

I have another one suggestion for you. You can add a Dictionary and put your list there where key - will be your Send with message type = "receive" Then you can simply order Dictionary by key. Check this code:

```
        List<Send> messages = new List<Send>();

    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="0_message" , Port = "PortA", Type="Receive" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="1_message" , Port = "PortA", Type="transmit" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="3_message" , Port = "PortA", Type="transmit" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="7_message" , Port = "PortA", Type="transmit" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="8_message" , Port = "PortA", Type="Receive" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="9_message" , Port = "PortA", Type="transmit" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="2_message" , Port = "PortB", Type="Receive" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="4_message" , Port = "PortB", Type="Receive" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="5_message" , Port = "PortB", Type="transmit" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="6_message" , Port = "PortB", Type="transmit" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="10_message" , Port = "PortB", Type="Receive" });
    messages.Add(new Send() {messageName ="11_message" , Port = "PortB", Type="transmit" });


     Dictionary<Send, List<Send>> myDict = new Dictionary<Send, List<Send>>();
        List<Send> mylist2 = new List<Send>();
        Send messagename = new Send();
        int i = 0;


        foreach (Send s in messages)
        {
            if (s.Type == "Receive" || s.Type == "receive")
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    myDict.Add(messagename, mylist2);
                }
                messagename = s;
                mylist2 = new List<Send>();
            }
            else
            {
                mylist2.Add(s);
            }

            if(i== messages.Count()-1)
            {
                myDict.Add(messagename, mylist2);
            }

            i++;
        }

        var q = myDict.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Key.messageName.Split('_')[0]));
```

If you want, you can convert dictionary back to list:

```
        List<Send> newlist = new List<Send>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Send, List<Send>> k in q)
        {
            newlist.Add(k.Key);

            foreach (Send s in k.Value)
            {
                newlist.Add(s);
            }
        }
```